# Changing numbers in a string

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame. However, I have similar IDs and these were different observations. What I am trying to do is change the last/last two digit(s) in the column "ID". So, ID alnfru_00001 in row 5 should be alnfru_00006 and row 34 should be carlin_00005 instead of carlin_00001 and so on. This sequence is seen right throughout the data frame even with other IDs. Can anyone provide some assistance?

Should I try to group the data first?

Note: I do not want the trailing number to track the row number

```
           ID          PFT        area
    1    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    2    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    3    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    4    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    5    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    6    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    7    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    8    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    9    alnfru_00005 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    26   calcan_00001 calcan Yukon_Delta
    27   calcan_00002 calcan Yukon_Delta
    28   calcan_00003 calcan Yukon_Delta
    29   calcan_00004 calcan Yukon_Delta
    30   carlin_00001 carlin Yukon_Delta
    31   carlin_00002 carlin Yukon_Delta
    32   carlin_00003 carlin Yukon_Delta
    33   carlin_00004 carlin Yukon_Delta
    34   carlin_00001 carlin Yukon_Delta
    18   alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    19   alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    20   alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    21   alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    22   alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    23   alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    24   alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    25   alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
```

The data frame should look like this

```
        ID          PFT        area
1    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
2    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
3    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
4    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
5    alnfru_00005 alnfru Yukon_Delta
6    alnfru_00006 alnfru Yukon_Delta
7    alnfru_00007 alnfru Yukon_Delta
8    alnfru_00008 alnfru Yukon_Delta
9    alnfru_00009 alnfru Yukon_Delta
26   calcan_00001 calcan Yukon_Delta
27   calcan_00002 calcan Yukon_Delta
28   calcan_00003 calcan Yukon_Delta
29   calcan_00004 calcan Yukon_Delta
30   carlin_00001 carlin Yukon_Delta
31   carlin_00002 carlin Yukon_Delta
32   carlin_00003 carlin Yukon_Delta
33   carlin_00004 carlin Yukon_Delta
34   carlin_00005 carlin Yukon_Delta
18   alnfru_00010 alnfru Yukon_Delta
19   alnfru_00011 alnfru Yukon_Delta
20   alnfru_00012 alnfru Yukon_Delta
21   alnfru_00013 alnfru Yukon_Delta
22   alnfru_00014 alnfru Yukon_Delta
23   alnfru_00015 alnfru Yukon_Delta
24   alnfru_00016 alnfru Yukon_Delta
25   alnfru_00017 alnfru Yukon_Delta
```

Comment: Hello, i think it would help to stat some replacing rules. Like if ID is unique it is allways correct, no matter what possition. If ID is not unique the one with the lower current rownumber is taken as correct, the one with the higher rownumber gets the first not appearing number within its group....

Answer (score 2):

Could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PFT, area) %>%
  mutate(
    ID = as.character(ID),
    ID = paste0(substr(ID, 1, nchar(ID) - nchar(row_number())), row_number()))
```

Output:

```
             ID    PFT        area
1  alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
2  alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
3  alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
4  alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
5  alnfru_00005 alnfru Yukon_Delta
6  alnfru_00006 alnfru Yukon_Delta
7  alnfru_00007 alnfru Yukon_Delta
8  alnfru_00008 alnfru Yukon_Delta
9  alnfru_00009 alnfru Yukon_Delta
10 calcan_00001 calcan Yukon_Delta
11 calcan_00002 calcan Yukon_Delta
12 calcan_00003 calcan Yukon_Delta
13 calcan_00004 calcan Yukon_Delta
14 carlin_00001 carlin Yukon_Delta
15 carlin_00002 carlin Yukon_Delta
16 carlin_00003 carlin Yukon_Delta
17 carlin_00004 carlin Yukon_Delta
18 carlin_00005 carlin Yukon_Delta
19 alnfru_00010 alnfru Yukon_Delta
20 alnfru_00011 alnfru Yukon_Delta
21 alnfru_00012 alnfru Yukon_Delta
22 alnfru_00013 alnfru Yukon_Delta
23 alnfru_00014 alnfru Yukon_Delta
24 alnfru_00015 alnfru Yukon_Delta
25 alnfru_00016 alnfru Yukon_Delta
26 alnfru_00017 alnfru Yukon_Delta
```

Comment: Not trying to bash on your answer, but wouldn't this replace row number 5 (current: alnfru_00001) by alnfru_00005 and rownumber 9 (current: alnfru_00005) by alnfru_00009?

Comment: Yes, exactly as it is in the expected output

Comment: Yes, you are right :) But the expected output could also be a resort with original rownumber 9 data beeing swaped to row number 5, original row number 5 beeing changed from alnfru_00001 to alnfru_00006 and swaped to row number 6. I think its hard to tell what the desired output is without an id-column that makes each row unique.

Comment: Hm not sure I understand. The logic I see is row numbers per each group regardless of row numbers of data frame as a whole. If OP disagrees he'll tell us

Comment: Once again, im not trying to put down your answer because i think its a great solution. The only thing i want so say is, that it might violate op's requirements in his startingpost: So, ID alnfru_00001 in row 5 should be alnfru_00006

Comment: I see what you mean now, there's a conflict between text and desired output, let's just see where this goes